# Exception with Logstash and Lumberjack

Tags: .net, ruby, logstash, logstash-forwarder

I'm looking into the the ELK stack for logging (ie. ElasticSearch, LogStash, and Kibana). Most of my logs are going to come from .NET services where I'm using NLog as the logging framework.

I'm having trouble getting my logs into Logstash though. A bit of research suggests that I should be able to use the Lumberjack protocol as a Logstack input, and there's a Nuget package for Nlog ([NLog.Targets.Lumberjack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Targets.Lumberjack)).

I've installed the ELK stack using Docker ([as described here](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk)), and this seems to work in the sense that the three container start up, and I can connect to them, and also visit the Kibana user interface.

I've also updated the Logstack.conf file to specify Lumberjack as an input:

```
input {
    lumberjack {
        port => 5000
        ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/logstashcerts/logstash.crt"
        ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/logstashcerts/logstash.key"
    }
}
```

That certificate was generated with the following command:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout logstash.key -out logstash.crt -nodes -subj /C=GB/ST=Oxfordshire/L=Oxford/O=*****/OU=****/CN=****
```

I'm using Windows, and just working locally for now, so also imported the certifcate into my local store and have a certificate thumbprint.

I took the example NLog.config file from the [NLog.Targets.Lumberjack](https://github.com/kaa/nlog.targets.lumberjack) nuget package, and the only change I made was to change the port to 5000 as per the Docker compose file, and also added the `thumbnail` argument to match the certificate I imported.

The problem is that when my .NET code sends a log entry via NLog, the Logstash console shows the following exception:

> logstash_2 | {:timestamp=>"2016-11-14T14:08:13.377000+0000", :message=>"Lumberjack input: unhandled exception", :exception=>#, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-lumberjack-0.0.26/lib/lumberjack/server.rb:225:in `handle_version'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-lumberjack-0.0.26/lib/lumberjack/server.rb:210:in`header'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-lumberjack-0.0.26/lib/lumberjack/server.rb:163:in `feed'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-lumberjack-0.0.26/lib/lumberjack/server.rb:332:in`read_socket'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/jls-lumberjack-0.0.26/lib/lumberjack/server.rb:315:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-lumberjack-2.0.4/lib/logstash/inputs/lumberjack.rb:110:in`invoke'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/concurrent-ruby-0.9.1-java/lib/concurrent/executor/executor_service.rb:515:in`run'", "Concurrent$$JavaExecutorService$$Job_1581663657.gen:13:in `run'"], :level=>:error}

So to try and track down the reason, I've connected to the Docker logstack container, getting a bash prompt so that I can view the source code in the callstack.

It seems to be falling over in the following code ...

```
def handle_version(version, &block)
  if supported_protocol?(version)
    yield :version, version
  else
    raise "unsupported protocol '#{version}'"
  end
end

def supported_protocol?(version)
  SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS.include?(version)
end
```

Ie. it's throwing the exception which suggests that `SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS` doesn't contain whatever `version` is.

However, `SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS` is this:

```
PROTOCOL_VERSION_1 = "1".ord
PROTOCOL_VERSION_2 = "2".ord

SUPPORTED_PROTOCOLS = [PROTOCOL_VERSION_1, PROTOCOL_VERSION_2]
```

And according to the callstack, `version` is 1. So to my untrained Ruby eye (I know nothing about Ruby!), it looks like it shouldn't be hitting that exception.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am seeing the exact same issue.

Comment: I don't think I did, although I can't remember what I did do (it was a few companies ago I'm afraid). I think I did it without using Lumberjack, but I'm afraid I really can't remember what protocol I did get it working with. Either way, this was just to trial the ELK stack as an alternative to the LogEntries service we were currently using, and we decided to stick with that.